# Can't generate and view dashboard generated reports in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

In windows, using the command "jmeter -n -t [test JMX file] -l [test log file] -e -o " to generate the dashboard result doesn't execute and shows the following error:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKEKR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a mistake in your command in the option:

> -l jmeter.log

-l references the results file not the jmeter.log file. JMeter is telling you that the file is not empty while it should be.

So you must rewrite your command to:

> jmeter -n -t  -l results.csv -j jmeter.log -e -o

For reference:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui

Comment: Would you please make me clear about which two types of files we should use in above command? I mean for 
1) [test jmx file] I am using the test script that I have recorded through test script recorder.
2) For [test log file] I am using the jmeter.log file from apache-jmeter-3.0 directory
3) For [path to output] I am giving the folder location where i want to save the dashboard report.
     Is this right?

Comment: Thanks. Got the solutions.